# Passing ViewBag value from ActionLink to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, null, actionlink

I am trying to pass the privApplicationId (retrieved from the ViewBag) to an ActionResult in my controller

Layout Cshtml page:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Comments", "ViewComments", "SubmittedApplications", new { @area = "Privileging" }, new { privApplicationId = @ViewBag.PrivApplicationId })
```

However, everytime it goes into the ActionResult, the privApplicationId value is null.

Controller ActionResult:

```
 public ActionResult ViewComments(long? privApplicationId)
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You picked the wrong overload of `ActionLink` helper. `new { privApplicationId = @ViewBag.PrivApplicationId }` is passed as `htmlAttribute` parameter, but should be `routeValue`. Try this way:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Comments", "ViewComments", "SubmittedApplications",
      new { area = "Privileging", privApplicationId = @ViewBag.PrivApplicationId }, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@` from `ViewBag` and pass null as last argument.
This should work

```
@Html.ActionLink("Comments", 
                 "ViewComments", 
                 "SubmittedApplications", 
                  new 
                  { 
                      area = "Privileging", 
                      privApplicationId = ViewBag.PrivApplicationId 
                  }, 
                  null)
```